# BLDC providing boost to rectifier circuit

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, boost, rectifier, braking, regenerative

I have been tasked to work on this project, and I have struggled to find clear resources that nicely explain the full concept and would appreciate some help. Here is all the information.

- There is a half bridge active rectifier circuit applying power to wind turbine control system
- Instead of using a traditional boost converter alongside, I would use a BLDC motor with regenerative braking capabilities.
- Two phases of the motor are shorted
- Current build up between two of the upper or lower level MOSFETs
- Opening one of the MOSFET allows for the sudden voltage rise with subsequent discharge (thanks to generator and cable intrinsic inductance)

Ultimately, I've been unable to find a lot of resources on regenerative baking in non-EV applications. I still don't fully understand this concept and need some advice on where to find info about it (textbooks, research papers etc.). I would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Please include the circuit you are trying to describe.

Comment: `Here is all the information` given in a test/assignment? Conceivable, but then, there needs to be more context. *in a utility wind turbine project*? Harder. Where does the energy come from you try to harvest from the motor/generator/machine? What's the idea with shorting two phases? How much power does the control system need, what voltage(s)? What is a *boost to a rectifier circuit*?